# validate pdf in Selenium using chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

When I click on a link in a page, a PDF opens. I need to validate the contents of this PDF file using Selenium in C#.

I'm able to handle this in Firefox 25(using pdf.js). In firefox, the contents of this pdf are displayed in html and hence, using isTextPresent, I am able to validate if the pdf contents are correct.

But, though Chrome opens the pdf in my browser, it does not show the pdf contents as separate elements. Is there any plugin/ setting change that can be done for me to view the pdf as html in Chrome browsewr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF.js is also available for Chrome - see [PDF Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) in the Chrome Web Store.

I suggest to load the PDF using the following URL: `chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/content/web/viewer.html?file=<URL-encoded version of PDF file's location>`.

The reason for explicitly putting the URL as shown before is that if the PDF url is visited *before the extension is loaded*, then the default PDF behavior is triggered (in Chromium, the file is downloaded, in Chrome, it's displayed using Chrome's built-in PDF Viewer).
After the PDF.js is loaded, you can directly type the URL for a PDF file in the omnibox, the extension automatically detects PDF files and renders the result (based on MIME-type).