# Plug-in not supported for embedded pdf in Webdriver Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Very recently when running chromedriver I am no longer able to view embedded pdf's.  Where the pdf should display is now gray with the puzzle piece saying 'this plugin is not supported'

I have verified that it displays in chrome when not running webdriver and also added:
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--always-authorize-plugins=true");

I have also verified via chrome://plugins that Chrome PDF Viewer is enabled.

Chrome version is : Version 42.0.2311.90 m

This is a new error and the same code was working earlier this month so it isn't like it has never worked.  Is anyone else having this issue or found a fix?

Comment: I don't see any problem in the config. Why don't you try doing a fresh install of Chrome or the plugin? Or you can see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135060/validate-pdf-in-selenium-using-chrome-browser

Comment: I believe the issue here is slightly different in that the pdf is supposed to be embedded as it requires an e-signature so I have no url available to open it.  I don't need to verify the contents only that it is available for the user to view.  I did try and reinstall chrome but no change.

Comment: In looking at the linked post the issue is that I am not trying to use js to open the pdf.  I am not trying to open it separately.  I am trying to verify, as is, that an embedded pdf is displayed and in Chrome it will only disply plugin is not supported.

Comment: As pee [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/A3XrBbHD80U) thread, the NPAPI plugins are no longer available for Chrome 42, but the Chrome PDF Viewer plugin should work. Why dont you try using an older version of Chrome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861506/object-tag-showed-pdf-in-chrome-upto-v41-but-displays-blank-in-v42-recent-vers

Must see