# Object tag showed PDF in Chrome upto v41, but displays blank in v42 (Recent version)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, pdf

I've an application in production mode which is working very fine until now. I've used `<object>` tag to display a PDF by providing base64 encoded data to object tag. Even if I dont have Adobe reader plugin, Chrome displays it correctly coz of it's internal pdf plugin. But today, I've updated my Chrome from v41 to v42 (Recent version), now the `<object>` contains data to be displayed but it's not showed in the screen. It's showing a blank content. But if I open that pdf in new tab, it's showing correctly. First I've used `<embed>` tag, but due to afraid of Cross browser support, I've used `<object>` tag.

Does really `<object>` tag is not supported in all browsers? It's very strange that Chrome displays it until v41 but not in v42.. Damn..

Comment: same here. I am using embed tag, but the result is same :(

Comment: @GauravSaini , It's a bug in the Google chrome. You can see the bug issue thread here.. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477866 , Its sad to see that it's still unresolved.